# del or listl.remove dont work python 3.5

Tags: python-3.5, del

This programm have to order a list of numbersbut every time i become a error can you help me to fix it? I hope somebody has an idea. I hzave also tried to us del list[(thenumber of the element or the number)]

```
# list = list with the none ordert number
# newlist = with the ordert numbers
# pnumbver = privious number
# add = new number for list
# numberelemente = how many numbers get in list
# length = length of list
# i = counting up for the stop




from random import randint

list = []
newlist = []
numberelemente = 10
while numberelemente > 0:
    add = randint(-100, 100)
    list.append(add)
    numberelemente = numberelemente - 1

print(list)

pnumber=list[0]
length = len(list)
i = 0


while i < length:
    for zahl in list:
       if number < pnumber:
            pnumber = number
    list.remove(pnumber)
    newlist.append(pnumber)
    i = i+1

print(newlist)
```

but i become this error i become them every time

```
eenter code her>>> runfile('C:/Users/Max/Desktop/python/liste ordnen.py', wdir='C:/Users/Max/Desktop/python')
[89, 46, 68, -30, 93, 38, -73, 91, 33, -69]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
 File "C:/Users/Max/Desktop/python/liste ordnen.py", line 29, in <module>
    list.remove(vzahl)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: Hello Max, you can debug the program using `import pdb` and `pdb.set_trace()`, also in the above program pnumber does not exists in your list therefore ValueError is thrown by python, try to handle such errors using `try except` block in python

Answer (score 0):

I never say that you added pnumber to list so it cant delete it. Don't you mean to use.

```
list.append(pnumber)
```

This is what `list.remove()` does

> list.remove(x)
>
> ### Remove the first item from the list whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

-https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Hope this helps.